# Overcoming the SQL Server Express Edition limitation

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express edition has a database size limit to 10GB. Now, is that just for a single instance or the overall size that the edition will allow? Or does that means that I can have as many databases using the edition provided each database is less than 10GB?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx):

> SQL Server Express includes 10GB of storage per database

and from [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014, Cross-Box Scale Limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx#Anchor_0):

> Maximum relational database size: 10 GB

This latter reference makes it clearer that the 10GB limit **per database** is applied to *relational data*, so it excludes log files* as well as `FILESTREAM` and FileTable data (both [supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx#Anchor_8) in Express Edition).

---

*<sub>* See [Database size limitation in SQL Express](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2014/02/25/database-size-limitation-in-sql-express/) by Arvind Shyamsundar</sub>*